# Showing date and time in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following data:

x: minutes over 2 months (so x has a length of `2*60*24*60`)
y: numerical data corresponding to each minute of a day over 2 months

When I plot data, I want to show on the x-axis the dates in the format of month-day and when plot is zoomed the hour and minute of each day to be displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you google the question title, this comes up: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-dates-and-durations.html Why is this not working for you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetick`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to do that. When you do not specify a format, MATLAB automatically adjusts the scale when zooming.

If your date aren't in [`datenum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenumhtml) format, change those first, e.g.

```
% Convert your starting time to a datevec
date_start = datevec('1995/03/21 12:38:15');
% Extend for all required times
date_mat = repmat(date_start, numel(x), 1);
% Add a minute to each row
date_mat (:, 5) = date_mat (:,5) + (0:numel(x)-1).';
datenum_array = datenum(date_mat);
```

Comment: Only if `The axis data values [are] serial date numbers, as returned by the datenum function` (from the docs), where datenum units are days. The OP suggests his x-axis units are minutes (since some unspecified time), so maybe easier to just convert the x data using `datetime` and then datetick will be the default axis behaviour anyway?

Comment: @Wolfie good point about converting the timestamps first, I added that. A `datetime` is still just a float number, so IIRC you'll need to explicitly call `datetick`, as opposed to e.g. Python's matplotlib, which has the default behaviour to format an axis as time when being fed a datetime64 object.

Comment: testing in 20b with `d=datetime('now')+days(1:5);y=rand(size(d));plot(d,y)` I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12aaY.png which has a date axis